# URL Rewrite Module appendQueryString

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm having the following problem ..

The Rewrite is concatenating the querystring in the URL of the page where there is a postback.

That is, I have a search page with pagination and it works perfectly. But when I click to go to the second page the address is this:

```
http://localhost/aaa/bbb/search-result?q=ccc
```

for this

```
http://localhost/aaa/bbb/search-result?param1=aaa&param2=bbb-0&page=% 2fsearch-result
```

Have we set the appendQueryString to false. But without success ..

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to override this tag < form id="form1" runat="server"> tag as shown in this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx Go to this url and search for "Handling Postbacks" I think that could help you